# PHP include_once a link causes creating different cookie after every include statement

Tags: php, jquery, json, cookies

**Problem:**
i try to retrieve JSON data, which should come back after i am logged in with a previous login link.
Before i can get the json data i have to login first with a previous link:

'...server.net/System?action=login&user=ro&password=12'

gives me back=>  {"Result":"OK","Role":"admin"}
which says that i am logged in.

A call of the specific second link:

'...server.net/System?action=getAllTransfers'

gives me back=>  {"Result":"ERROR","Reason":"Invalid Session ID"}
which means that i am not logged in.

> include_once('server.net/System?action=login&user=ro&password=12');
>
> **Header returned:**
> Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 [2] => Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F2981D6C0C67011234B2E8B9F067FECF; Path=/ixaropagersystem/; HttpOnly [3] => Content-Length: 30 [4] => Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 08:13:00 GMT [5] => Connection: close )
>
> include_once('server.net/System?action=getAllTransfers');
>
> **Header returned:**
> Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 [2] => Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=62D3828A1DB0E9DE91649D6F0E8016B0; Path=/ixaropagersystem/; HttpOnly [3] => Content-Length: 48 [4] => Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 08:13:00 GMT [5] => Connection: close )

The Problem is, i dont stay logged in after sending the correct login and password and try to get the json data. Somehow my php server which is calling the first and second link with php include_once('...') gets every time a new JSESSIONID cookie from the server that should give me back the json data.

**Question**: Is there a way to overcome this behaviour or just to predefine a cookie (jsessionId) for include_once which can be send from my php server to the other server which receives the jsessionId cookie? beacause i get with every called link a new jsessionId from the other server and i dont know how to hold the session

When i put in the link manually into my firefox, it works as it should. But with include_once it is not working.

I Have to say, that i cannot set the Header for allowing CORS or have permissions to change the code on the other server somehow.

Many Thx!

Comment: while setting cookie you can set path of the session cookie.  This problem can be solved by session_set_cookie_params() php function.

Comment: Hello vartika, thank you for your response. What i tried to reach is to get the old JSESSIONID which was used in the login link.    session_set_cookie_params ( 1600, '/System', 'server.net' );
$cookie = session_get_cookie_params ();
while ( list ( $key, $val ) = each ( $cookie ) ) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
}

Comment: Or even better how no to get always new jsessionid with every link call and stay at the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally i have found something that works fine:

**Solution:**
The second link has to be called in such way that a cookie which was catched by calling the first link and the correct login process will be send with the 2nd request.

```
# get the cookie
$firstLink = 'server.net/System?action=login&user=ro&password=12';
$headers = get_headers($firstLink);
$cookie = substr($headers[2], 4);

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"POST",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: pl\r\n" .

            $cookie // == 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=B1BA33657E8DD2CD1736C10B62D61DC4\r\n'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

# oppens the 2nd link with specific cookie in the HTTP-Header
$secondLink = 'server.net/System?action=getAllTransfers';    
$expectedOutput = file_get_contents($secondLink , false, $context);
echo $expectedOutput;
```